# Import Java library into Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, github

Is there any way to import this library https://github.com/timmolter/XChange from github into Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The library says:

> Maven
>
> The XChange release artifacts are hosted on Maven Central.
>
> Add the following dependencies in your pom.xml file. You will need at
>   least xchange-core. Add the additional dependencies for the exchange
>   modules you are interested in (XYZ shown only for a placeholder).
>   There is example code for all the modules in xchange-examples.

```
 <dependency>   
     <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>  
     <artifactId>xchange-core</artifactId>   
     <version>4.2.1</version>
 </dependency> 
 <dependency>   
     <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>  
     <artifactId>xchange-examples</artifactId>   
     <version>4.2.1</version>
 </dependency> 
 <dependency>   
     <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>  
     <artifactId>xchange-XYZ</artifactId>   
     <version>4.2.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

---

Therefore you can do

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral() // <-- add that
    }
}
```

And

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.knowm.xchange:xchange-core:4.2.1'
```